# NGINX: serve ONLY specific file types in all directories

Tags: linux, nginx

I need to **only** serve .vmdk and .vmx files on a virtual server, no matter what directory level. This is my current configuration (right now it serves all, but if I uncomment the lower part it serves nothing):

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name vmdk;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    root /srv/vmdk/public;

    location ~ (./?|\vmdk|\vmx)$ {
            autoindex on;
    }


    #location / {
    #       deny all;
    #}

}
```

How do I achieve this?

If it is easier to achieve with Apache, then an example Apache configuration is also appreciated.

Comment: You regexp is strange.

Comment: @AlexeyTen It's probably wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  vmdk;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    root /srv/vmdk/public;

    location / {
        deny all;                     # deny by default

        location ~ "\.(vmdk|vmx)$" {
            allow all;                # allow vm disk images, etc.
        }

        location ~ "/$" {
            allow all;
            autoindex on;             # allow listing directory contents
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get 403 Forbidden with this config.

Comment: If I add a "test.vmdk" in "/" I can open "/test.vmdk", but I can't see the directory listing anywhere, which I need.

Comment: `error.log` says: `*1 access forbidden by rule, ...`

Comment: @teelf the answer provided by Alexey answers the question you originally asked.  The matter of listing directory contents is separate.  To achieve that, you could try the ``autoindex on;`` directive.  Note that ``deny all;`` may conflict with ``autoindex``.

Comment: @teelf I amended Alexey's good answer with the detail you requested.

Comment: What if I want an index file anyway without explicity having to type `/index.html`? Actually we want the deny all, but it's also blocking the index file call